# Instantaneous displacement of infinite square well walls

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

I have an infinite square well of width 2a centered at the origin with eigenstates $$\psi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{2a}\right)$$ for odd n and

$$\psi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{2a}\right)$$ for even n with eigenenergies $$E_{n} = \frac{\hbar^{2} \pi^{2} n^{2}}{2a}$$.

If the walls are suddenly displaced from $x=-a$ and $x=a$ to $x=-3a$ and $x=3a$, how do I obtain the probability of finding the particle in the lowest 2 states?

I think that the instantaneous displacement doesn't cause the wavefunctions to change, so do I do the integrals $$\int_{-3a}^{3a}\psi^{*}\hat{H}\psi dx$$ for $n=2$ and $n=3$? What would $\hat{H}$ be in this case?

Comment: I assume you are interested in the instant of time after the walls have moved.  (?)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the wave function should remain the same before and after the displacement. However, the integral $\int_{-3a}^{3a}\psi^*\hat{H}\psi dx$ does not give you the probability of finding the particle in a particular state. It gives you the expectation value of the energy. To calculate the probability that a particle in initial state $\psi$ will be found in some other state $\phi$ (in your case, $\phi$ would be the wavefunction of either the first or second energy state of the new Hamiltonian), you need to calculate the integral
$$\int \psi^*(x)\phi(x)$$
and take the modulus squared to get the probability.